# ReactJS and FabricJS issue: Image disappear on canvas pan/zoom

Tags: reactjs, canvas, fabricjs

I was trying to implement a feature where you can drag and drop an image onto the canvas using ReactJS and FabricJS. The problem is after draging and dropping the image onto the canvas, and when you try to pan/zoom the canvas, the image will disappear.

Wondering if the way I render is causing the issue

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Since I was trying the following syntax and it works fine. (But this is deprecated)

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Sandbox sample here 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-playground-forked-3zyffq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

React.StrictMode is causing the problem.

Comment: But shouldn't we use React.StrictMode in production apps?